# How do I evaluate non-SQL logic within a SQL call with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and trying to make an ActiveRecord `where` call.
I also want to evaluate logic during the call, so that I get an object returned where the SQL query and my logic is true.

```
def new_target
  #Need to make sure the array doesn't include the existing target
  t = robot.where(
    "name != :robot_name",
    {:robot_name => self.name}
  ).first
```

I'd like to say something like `!self.targets.include?` (the returned robot).

So I'm searching for all robots that have a different name than the current one, but want to make sure I don't already have them within this robot's target array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code can be something like

```
t=robot.where(
      "name!= :robot_name and name not in (:target_names) ", 
      {
         :robot_name => self.name,
         :target_names => self.targets.map{|robot| robot.name}
      }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out.
Unfortunately when I'm logging the name after and I see "target_name: Robot"
Any idea why the name is being set to the class name?

Comment: Can you past the query which is formed?.

Comment: There is small typo :target_name instead of :target_names. Which I just fixed. Can please post your schema too. May be I misunderstood the question.